# JIRA Rest API and Ampersand

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

When using the REST API, with a POST to /rest/api/2/search and using an ampersand in the search criteria of the JQL, i.e. "component = \"Research & Architecture\" "

I get the following error.

"The value 'Research %26 Architecture' does not exist for the field 'component'."

Is there a way to use the REST api without the values being encoded?

I am using postman as a client directly to the Jira REST API. I have also used a nodejs client npm package jira-connector, with the same results.

Comment: Can you update with what client you are using for calling the rest api? and how you are making the rest call

Comment: I only see error "The quoted string 'Research ' has not been completed."
Can you post complete rest api example url you are hitting, hiding business details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use the JQL Search REST API to search for issues with a component containing an ampersand by encoding the `&` character as `%26`:

`https://jira-url/rest/api/2/search/?jql=component='Research %26 Architecture'`

This is one solution in case you can't find a way to avoid the values being encoded.

Comment: This is a good alternate solution. I did not realize the search operation supports a GET and a POST.  I will mark this as the correct solution